# Threads waiting for Shared Resources

Tags: java

Is there any way for the current thread holding the resource, to know how many threads are still in the queue for the shared resource or waiting for the resource

Comment: You might need extend Threads to include that functionality.

Comment: No thread wont know unless you do some queuing etc.

Comment: What about using a ReentrantLock?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: I guess you can do it using final methods that allow threads to communicate about the locked status of a resource. These methods are wait(), notify().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getQueueLength](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#getQueueLength%28%29,%20but) method from Semaphore class to get the count of waiting threads.

sample code can be

```
try 
{
    semaphore.acquire();
    //your code goes here
    semaphore.release();
} 
catch (InterruptedException ex)
{
   //some code
}
```